Kendo Chart Angular - X axis numeric type - no number intervals
I have a Kendo Chart in Angular:
                     <div class="sensor-graph"><!--Strength-->
                        <div class="value-name">Strength ({{sensor.lastKnownStrength}})</div>
                                    <kendo-chart
                                    [transitions]="false"
                                    [chartArea]="{background: 'var(--table-header)'}"
                                    [legend]="{visible: false}"
                                    [seriesColors]="seriesColors"
                                    [tooltip]="{visible: true}"
                                    [axisDefaults]="{majorGridLines: { dashType:'dot', visible: true}}">
                                    
                                    <kendo-chart-value-axis>
                                      <kendo-chart-value-axis-item
                                        type="numeric">
                                      </kendo-chart-value-axis-item>
                                    </kendo-chart-value-axis>

                                    <kendo-chart-category-axis>
                                      <kendo-chart-category-axis-item 
                                        [categories]="sensor.strengthCategories"
                                        [visible]="false">
                                      </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
                                    </kendo-chart-category-axis>
        
                                    <kendo-chart-series>
                                      <kendo-chart-series-item
                                        [markers]="{ visible: false }"
                                        [color]="seriesColors[1]"
                                        name="Strength"
                                        type="area"
                                        field="value"
                                        [line]="{ width: 1 }"
                                        [tooltip]="{ visible: true, format: '{0}' }"
                                        [missingValues]="'interpolate'"
                                        [data]="sensor.strengthHistory">
                                        </kendo-chart-series-item>
                                    </kendo-chart-series>
        
                                    <kendo-chart-tooltip>
                                      <ng-template kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate let-category="category" let-value="value">
                                        {{ category }} | {{ value }}
                                      </ng-template>
                                    </kendo-chart-tooltip>
                                    </kendo-chart>
                                    {{ sensor.strengthCategories[0] }} / {{ sensor.strengthCategories[sensor.strengthCategories.length - 1] }}        
                                    </div>
                                    <br>

categories are type - 'number':
sensorData.strengthCategories.push((item.sensor_ts_utc) as number)

chart:
enter image description here
THE PROBLEM:
The X axis is not showing intervals, the distances are not proportional as it should be. For example: the distance between 100 and 10000 can be the same as between 100 and 101.
I was trying to add [majorUnit] or [minorUnit] but the intervals are the same.
ChatGPT is not very helpful, the documentation is not clear about it: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/XAxis/
Btw. I do know how to make Categories as time and I succeeded with configuring time intervals. But I need to have X axis as numeric in this case.
